# How to resolve same module name from multiple gems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

I have two gems installed named `libarchive` and `libarchive-ruby`. Both needs `require archive` line. But the problem is, when I want to use the archive library from `libarchive-ruby`, I can't. Ruby goes to the one from `libarchive`.

Is there any way to tell Ruby which library I want to use? I know, I can uninstall one but is there any other better option?

Comment: you can use `autoload` if you know the path to the `archive` library, see http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-techniques-revealed-autoload-1652.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `Bundler` to manage your dependencies:

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'libarchive-ruby', :require => 'archive'
```

**whatever.rb**

```
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require :default  # :default is the group name of the implicit group

# Your code
```